# Sharing transaction scope between threads in python/django? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions, psycopg2, django-testing

Is there any way to share same transaction between two threads in a django-based code?

The problem is that I have 1.1's TestCase (those that wrap individual tests into transactions) that are intended to test code that is running in a different thread [a sort of asynchronous testing]. So these test create some data that is intended to be used by this second thread. Obviously, since this data is created within a transaction scope, it is not visible to the second thread. But since that should basically be the same connection to PgSQL (should it?) I hope there is a way to share this transaction scope so my second thread can access data being added within it?..

Any idea?

Database is PgSQL 8.3, driver is postgresql_psycopg2. Django — trunk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that's impossible. To my knowledge, each thread has its own PostgreSQL session to be able to run concurrently. And given that PostgreSQL is an [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) database, one thread will not have access to the other's changes, until the transaction is committed – which it won't be in the case of a  Django 1.1 `TestCase`.

If you need to test stuff that runs concurrently, I'm pretty sure that you need to use a [`TransactionTestCase`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TransactionTestCase).

Comment: TransactionTestCase is killing me — for some reason TRUNCATE is taking *forever* to complete...

Comment: Have you checked if the second thread has been stopped before the test ends? It might cause the truncation to run a lot more slowly, since per MVCC, PostgreSQL has to store a copy of the truncated data.

Comment: hm, that's interesting.. the whole idea was not to stop background thread throughout all tests lifetime. in this case I might just consider starting and stopping 2nd thread in each setUp and tearDown, respectively.

Comment: I think you are correct when it comes to using setUp and tearDown, but it depends a bit on the nature of your test. Generally, for the tests to be atomic, both threads would have to work on the same dataset, and starting a new thread for each test would probably be the most clean way to ensure that.

Comment: yeah, I thought about it before — just was sort of concerned that at some point 2nd thread startup might be not instant ;)

Comment: Yeah, well. Testing is slow, but then you have an excuse for hallway swordfights: http://xkcd.com/303/ :)